# Add jars dynamically while executing kitchen script

Tags: pentaho, kettle

While executing kitchen.sh, is there a way to specify the db2 jar path? Currently I have placed it in the lib folder. But while deploying in production environment I need to include the path to db2 jar (I will not be able to add it into the lib folder of data-integration) so that kitchen.sh doesn't throw an error. Is it possible to add the path of jar as an argument to kitchen.sh?!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post about something similar:

http://funpdi.blogspot.com/2015/04/command-line-utility-for-pdi.html

With kitchen.sh you might be able to add the library using the -lib parameter. If that doesn't work you can look at the last line of kitchen.sh (which actually calls spoon.sh) and use that as the starting point, then add the -lib stuff.